# applying css3 style to specific id

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I wanted to apply style only to the myPage id. But I am not able to achieve it with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<head>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"/>  
</head>  
<body>  
<div>  
Welcome To CSS3....  
Learning.....!  
</div>  
<div id="myPage">  
Welcome ....  
<img src="rose1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>  

.myPage div{  
border:2px solid black;  
background-color:yellow;  
font-color:red;  
box-shadow:10px 10px 7px #777  
}
```

Please tell me the fault.

Thanks

Sneha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` of your div is `myPage` , so to apply style to elements with `id` you must use `#`.
You should use `#myPage` div here.
The `.` is used for applying styles to a class.[Basic Reference.](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php)

Answer (score 5):

When you use this selector:

```
.myPage div
```

You are looking for an element with the *class* of `myPage`. You want this one instead:

```
#myPage div
```

The `.` looks for classes. The `#` looks for elements with the specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

when you given css style in page itself must be as below

< style>

// css code

< /style>

and the instead of using id -- #  you went for the class -- .
that was the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The selector is looking for the class myPage, with a div contained within it.

Try the following selector:

```
div#myPage { }
```

This will look for an element that is both a div and has the id of myPage.

The dot indicaties a class, the hash indicates an id. The selector `#myPage div` would indicate any element with the id myPage that has a div inside of it, not an element that is both a div and has an id of myPage.

Answer (score 0):

**.myPage div{}** this will apply css to div inside the element having a class **myPage** 
remember **"." for class and "#" for id** 
so just make a change like

```
<style>
    #myPage{  
    border:2px solid black;  
    background-color:yellow;  
    font-color:red;  
    box-shadow:10px 10px 7px #777  ;
    } 
</style>
```

it will solve your problem