# How do I apply CSS to this JS Fetch code to alter text position, font?

Tags: javascript, css

New to JS.  How can I apply CSS to this JS Fetch to alter test position, font?  Thank you.

```js
let file = 'art.txt';
    
const handleFetch = () => {
  fetch(file)
    .then((x) => x.text())
    .then((y) => (document.getElementById('kdkz').innerHTML = y));
};

setInterval(() => handleFetch(), 2000);
```

```html
 <p id="kdkz"></p>
```

Comment: Why not just adding the css in `<p id="kdkz"></p>` tag?

Comment: You can do element.style.[styleName] = "value".  ex :: element.style.padding = "20px";
This is for dynamic styles, but if you want a template then add it to the HTML as per the comment from @amlxv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [applying css3 style to specific id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974703/applying-css3-style-to-specific-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `handleFetch()` to:

```
const handleFetch = () => {
    fetch(file)
      .then((x) => x.text())
      .then((y) => {
        const target = document.getElementById('kdkz');
        target.innerHTML = y;
        target.style.textAlign = 'center'; // Change the position here.
      });
  };
```

Or, you can easily add style within the HTML document by using `<style>` tag before the `<body>`.

```
<style>
#kdkz {
  text-align: center; /* Change the position here */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
#kdkz {
  /*styling here*/
}
```

The browser will apply the styling after fetching.